# How to defragmantation subpartition table in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I want to defragmantation subpartitions table.
My question is should i rebuild all subpartition index and all partition index after compress subpartitions? Should i rebuild all normal index? Or is enough rebuild  just subpartition index?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You write "defragment", "compress", "rebuild". What do you mean by "normal index"? - I am not aware of any abnormal indexes in Oracle. What do you like to achieve? What is your table definition? Maybe have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162415/how-to-shrink-space-on-table-with-a-function-based-index

Comment: Actual oracle versions support `update indexes` clause: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#BABICDHJ